# SQL Server Stored procedure returning an unexpected value

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that is called from C# code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DepartmentStoreControlAccess]              
    @DeptId INT,             
    @intError tinyint OUTPUT,
AS
    SET @intError = 0

    SELECT @AccessTime = Hour
    FROM Entries
    WHERE DeptId = @DeptId

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
    BEGIN
        -- DO STUFF and update @intError
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0   
            SET @intError = 0
        ELSE
            SET @intError = -1 
    END
```

There is a case I know for sure that select:

```
SELECT @AccessTime = Hour
FROM Entries
WHERE DeptId = @DeptId
```

could return more than 1 row, let's say 2, 3, 4, .... , N so output parameter `@intError` should be returned to -1 in this case according to my stored procedure but I do not know why, the stored procedure in this case (when select returns more than 1 row) is returning 0 in the output parameter `@intError`. Why?

Comment: Unrelated, but you can't assign -1 to a tinyint variable. You would need to use smallint or larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the `@@ROWCOUNT` into a variable when you first access it the first time because `@@ROWCOUNT` [refers to the last statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql). In your `ELSE` case, `@@ROWCOUNT` returns 0 because your last statement was the `@@ROWCOUNT` in your `IF` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
 DECLARE @Count INT
 SELECT @AccessTime=Hour
 FROM   Entries                                                                       
 WHERE  DeptId=@DeptId
 SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
```

And use variable

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that checking @@ROWCOUNT resets the value in @@ROWCOUNT

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1   -- From this point @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    -- DO STUFF and update @intError
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0   -- So we always end up here
        set @intError = 0
    else
        set @intError = -1 
END
```